# iOS UIImageView why Instruments show less live bytes for ImageWithContentsOfFile instead of direct image assignment from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiimageview, memory-profiling

I've stumbled upon a peculiar live bytes issue when profiling my app with instruments. **I'm interested if this is any real "optimization", or an instruments glitch.** Is there any benefit to having less "live bytes" if overall real memory footprint stays the same? The real memory usage stays the same for both cases.

I'm using UIImagePicker in a popover controller, it picks an large (up to 7mb) image and assigns it to an image view like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {

    activeImageView.image = img;

}
```

Here's the allocations profiling for this operation. After 2 image assignments, the live bytes has grown for each image (by about 5.4 mb). You can see the malloc block for the images below the graph (5.4mb and 768kb) Once I replace one of the images with a new one(5. mb to 768kb), the live bytes does a "step down", as displayed in the graph at about 00:55:

[image]

The peculiarity that I'm talking about is that **if take this image, save it to disk and then I use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` as in code below, my live bytes looks very different:**

```
//this is what I use to save image to disk
     -(NSString* )saveImage:(UIImage*)image withID:(int)imageID 
{
        NSString* filepath = [[self imagesFolderPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",imageID]];


        BOOL success =   [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];

        if(!success)
        {
            DLog(@"failed to write to file: %@",filepath );
        }

        success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filepath];
        DLog(@"file created: %@",success?@"YES":@"NO");
        return filepath;
    }




//this is the popover delegate telling me when the user has dismissed the image picker in popover
        -(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
        {
                popoverController = nil;

    //take the image from the image view, write it to disk and assign back to the image view
                NSString* imageFilePath = [self saveImage:activeImageView.image withID:self.selectedID];

                if(imageFilePath)
                {
                    //this will work only for an existing icon file, otherwise 
                    imageView.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];
                }
        }
```

Upon introducing this code, my live bytes allocations looks like the image below. I repeat the same operations (assigning two images to UIImageView from the image picker, but here I add a method to write them to disk, then read them back from disk. (the triangular ramp comes from when I'm creating NSData from the image for writing to disk):

[image]